# Confusion with Bellard's algorithm for Pi

Tags: pi

I've found the following algorithm for calculating the nth digit of pi in base B:

[image: Algorithm]

It all makes sense, until you reach the $b=$ inside the second for loop. The whole line is:

$$b=\frac{k}{a^{v(n,k)}}$$
Specifically, the radical in the denominator:
$$v(n,k)$$
V is a variable, not a function. What does it mean to apply it as a function to n and k? This also appears many times past that in the algorithm. I've tried researching it, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortly $\,v(p,k)\,$ is the [multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#Multiplicity_of_a_prime_factor) of the prime $p$ in $k$ (the exponent of $p$ in the multiplicative decomposition of $k$ in prime powers, another name is ["p-adic **v**aluation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order#Definition_and_Properties)).
Example : $v(3,18)= 2\,$ since $\,18=2\cdot 3^2$.

In your case we are concerned with $\,a$-adic valuations since the $n$ in $\,v(n,k)$ appears to be a typo for '$a$' as you may see in this extract from Fabrice Bellard's $1997$ paper ["Computation of the n'th digit of $\pi$ in any base in $O(n^2)$"](http://bellard.org/pi/pi_n2.ps) (this is a .ps file) :

[image: Bellard's 1997 paper]
$$-$$
This paper, details as well as c source files are available at Bellard's site ["Pi Formulas, Algorithms and Computations"](http://bellard.org/pi/) and the file [pi.c](http://bellard.org/pi/pi.c) seems to correspond to the given algorithm in the case $B=10$.

Another paper from $2010$ is available ["Computation of 2700 billion decimal digits of Pi using a Desktop Computer"](http://www.bellard.org/pi/pi2700e9/pipcrecord.pdf).